# Не подключается jgrowl.css

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

На сайте есть кнопка "Сохранить", при нажатии ничего не происходит. Гугл консоль выдает ошибку: **Uncaught TypeError: $.jGrowl is not a function**

Подключил я значит .js

```
<script src="/application/public/widgets/jgrowl-notifications/jgrowl.js"></script>
```

Ошибки нет, функция **$.jGrowl** текст выводит как и положено, но только не применяется **jgrowl.css**, ибо он не подключен, поэтому наверное и не применяется.

Я подключаю его так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/application/public/widgets/jgrowl-notifications/jgrowl.css">
```

Тогда ошибки нет, но и текст пропал вообще, т.е - ни в каком виде не отображается.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Весь код:

```php
<?php defined("NET2FTP") or die("Direct access to this location is not allowed."); ?>
<style>
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-hover-primary:hover, .btn-hover-primary:active, .btn-hover-primary.active, .btn.btn-active-primary:active, .btn.btn-active-primary.active, .dropdown.open>.btn.btn-active-primary, .btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-active-primary {
  background-color: #579ddb;
  border-color: #5fa2dd;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
    <link href="/application/public/widgets/jgrowl-notifications/jgrowl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src='/application/public/widgets/jgrowl-notifications/jgrowl.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<!-- Template /skins/shinra/edit.template.php begin -->

<form id="<?php echo $formname; ?>" action="" method="post">
<?php   printLoginInfo(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="state"        value="edit" />
<input type="hidden" name="state2"       value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="directory"    value="<?php echo $net2ftp_globals["directory_html"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="screen"       value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="textareaType" value="<?php echo $textareaType; ?>" />
<table style="padding: 2px; width: 97%; height: 100%; border: 0px;">

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: <?php echo __("left"); ?>;">
            <div style="margin-<?php echo __("left"); ?>: 0px; text-align: <?php echo __("left"); ?>;">
<?php /* ----- Plain textarea ----- */ ?>
<?php       if ($textareaType == "" || $textareaType == "plain") { ?>
<?php // Do not use style="white-space: nowrap;" because then IE strips the carriage-return + linefeeds (tested on IE version 6.0) ?>
                <textarea name="text" class="edit" rows="33" style="color: #FFF;
background-color: #121921;
font-family: Inconsolata;width: 100%; height: 400px;margin-bottom: 10px;" wrap="off" onkeydown="TabText()"><?php echo $text ?></textarea>
<?php       } 
    /* ----- CKEditor or TinyMCE ----- */
            elseif ($textareaType == "ckeditor" || $textareaType == "tinymce") { ?>
                <div id="header_hidden"></div>
                <div id="header_shown" style="display: none;"><textarea name="text_splitted[top]" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"><?php echo $text_splitted["top"]; ?></textarea></div>

                <div id="body_hidden"></div>
                <div id="body_shown" style="display: block;"><textarea cols="120" rows="35" id="text_splitted[middle]" name="text_splitted[middle]"><?php echo $text_splitted["middle"]; ?></textarea></div>

                <div id="footer_hidden"></div>
                <div id="footer_shown" style="display: none;"><textarea name="text_splitted[bottom]" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"><?php echo $text_splitted["bottom"]; ?></textarea></div>
<?php           }
    /* ----- Ace ----- */
            elseif ($textareaType == "ace") { ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="text" value="" />
                <div id="editor" name="text"><?php echo $text; ?></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
                    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/<?php echo $ace_theme; ?>");
                    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/<?php echo $ace_mode; ?>");
                </script>
<?php       } ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr color="#c3c3c3">
        <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: <?php echo __("left"); ?>; width: 25%;">
        <button onClick="document.forms['<?=$formname?>'].screen.value=3; " class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
        </td> 

    </tr>
</table>
</form>
                          <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#<?=$formname?>').submit(function(e){
//отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
e.preventDefault();
//берем из формы метод передачи данных
var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
//получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
//получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
var m_data=$(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: m_method,
url: m_action,
data: m_data,
success: function(result){
$('#status').html(result);
$.jGrowl("Конфиг успешно сохранен!", { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-green" });
//$.jGrowl(data.success, { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-green" });
//toastr.success('</b> Конфиг успешно сохранен!');
}
});
});
});
</script>
<!-- Template /skins/shinra/edit.template.php end -->
```

Comment: Соберите минимальный воспроизводимый пример проблемы прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @VenZell, выложил весь код.

Comment: Нужен не "весь код", а минимальный самодостаточный пример для воспроизведения вашей проблемы. Вот на такой верстке проблема воспроизводится: **тут кусок вашей верстки**. Зачем отвечающим знать, как вы с помощью php формируете верстку? Почему не результирующую выложили?

Опять же подчеркну, нужен **минимальный** пример.

Comment: @VenZell, извините, но я вас не понимаю. Что значит, минимальный пример?

Comment: Вот ссылка на справку: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

jQuery забыл подключить. Можешь взять отсюда по [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery).

Выглядеть должно примерно так:

```
<head>
  <link href="http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/stylesheets/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/javascripts/jquery.growl.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $.growl({
        title: "Growl",
        message: "errits already released in SU or Submitted for SU!"
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Подробная инициализация [здесь](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/).

Comment: Я видел этот код. Не работает почему-то.

Comment: @Максим В консоли ошибки посмотри, скорее всего из-за этого.

Comment: в том то и дело, что ошибки нет. Если убрать growl.css, то текст пишется, но не так как положено, а как только подключаю growl.css - всё, ничего не происходит.